# Cannon run an overridden method

Tags: c++, multithreading, polymorphism

There is a class "Mario". This one has an virtual method: `void mission()`. I want override this method and run it from base class code in parallel.

But output of the following code is:

```
Mario works hard
LOL
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Mario
{
    std::thread workingField;
    bool hasStarted = false;

public:
    virtual void mission() 
    {
        std::cout << "LOL" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void startMission()
    {
        if (!hasStarted)
        {
            workingField = std::thread([this]() {
                this->mission();
            });
            hasStarted = true;
        }
    }
    virtual ~Mario()
    {
        if (hasStarted)
        {
            workingField.join();
        }
    }
};

class MarioWorker : public Mario
{
public:
    void mission() override final
    {
        std::cout << "Mario works hard" << std::endl;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MarioWorker mw;

    mw.mission();
    mw.startMission();
}
```

How can I get a double line *"Mario works hard"*, when one of them is executed in another thread?

In other words how a base class can execute an overridden method in parallel?

---

*I'm using GCC 9.3*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, the main thread is *too fast*. Your main method ends, the deconstruction of `mw` starts, `MarioWorker` gets destructed and once it starts destructing the `Mario` it joins the thread. The thread never sees the `MarioWorker` as it was already destructed, all it sees is the `Mario`.